# SPSS identification restrictions on EFA models

Tags: categorical-data, spss, degrees-of-freedom

I am trying to understand the restrictions used by SPSS to identify EFA models using ML extraction. FOr example the GFI for a 2 factor model of 8 items (shown below) has 13df

[image: GFI output in SPSS EFA]

I understand to identify EFA models m-squared restrictions are needed, where m=#of factors. I have also seen the formula [(p−m)2−(p+m)]/2 for the df of the chi-sq test.

This 2-factor model of 8 items needs 2^2=4 restrictions. We get 3 from fixing the factor var-covar matrix to 1 for factors and 0 for factor covarience.

How is the additional restriction obtained? 13 df mean one loading appears to be fixed to zero, or some restriction has been placed on a function of loadings. But the unrotated solution has 24 loadings reported, none of which are 0.

Even a text discussing how to restrict this model for estimation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The number of correlations obtained from 8 variables is 8*7/2=28. These are "data points". We estimate 8*2=16 loadings. However, these cannot all be uniquely estimated, and m(m-1)/2 must be fixed to zero (this is the so-called Leddermann bound). In this case, m=2, so this is 1. Thus, df= # of data points - the number of estimated parameters= 28-16+1=13.

Note that you don't see the zero loading in the solution because this is the initial extracted solution prior to rotation. The solution is then rotated to approximate simple structure, and the rotated loadings matrix will not show these constraints.

Comment: The point that rotation hides the zero loading is well taken. But how the item was selected a priori to get the zero loading is not clear. Once a solution is obtained, setting the lowest loading on a factor to zero is a strategy - but this cannot be done a priori.

I suspect some restriction is being placed across loadings, like sum to # items. This does not require choosing one item to have zero loading. Once you do that, you are in CFA territory.

But I cannot find any discussion confirming this type of restriction, or explicitly stating how the restriction is chosen.